# .net core 2.0 Razor pages VS 2017 Tabular data download

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I am new to web development with **Razor pages .net core VS 2017**.

I have **index page** that lists my data in the form of rows & columns using EF core Model.

I am also providing data filtering options via DropDowns and search box.

I want to export this tabular filtered/unfiltered data to excel. ---  For which i think i can use NPOI nuget package (http://www.talkingdotnet.com/import-export-excel-asp-net-core-2-razor-pages/).

I want to do this using asp-page-handler with button click.

**Questions**:
1. Will this be **GET** request or **POST** ?

2. How to pass data (e.g. model object with all data) to the page handler ?

Any help is Appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question about using GET or POST, both methods can be used but I personally use the POST method for cases like this.

For your second question I would not send to server all the filtered data but I would pass the filtering information which will be used in order to generate the data and export them to an Excel file.

**Update 1**

I made a simple example for you. Type the following html in your cshtml file:

```
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"> Export</button>
    <input asp-for="Value1" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input asp-for="Value2" type="hidden" value="2" />
</form>
```

The two inputs will be used in order to submit to the server values which will be used in order to filter your data. The following OnPost will return a static file but you can write your own code in order to return the filtered data and return them to the browser.

```
[BindProperty]
public int Value1 { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public int Value2 { get; set; }

public ActionResult OnPost()
{
    // example of returning a file
    return File("~/Images/accounts.png", "image/png", "FileNameForBrowser.png");
}
```

Comment: 1. Any particular reason for using POST over GET ??? with button tag can we use GET ? because i didnt get a hit to OnGetExport() while i got to OnPostExport()... Also Post request will require me to maintain page state (is it right ?). Any example how can i pass filteration parameters (a lot of ) to page handler ?

Comment: `<form method="post">
    <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-top:10px;">  
            Download in Excel:  
            <button asp-page-handler="Export">Download</button>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
    <br />  
</form>

Comment: Maintain your page state has nothing to do with the download action because you can set the target attribute of your form to be equal to _blank so that you will download the file. The web page will not be reloaded. You just want to download the file.

Comment: I tried with target = _blank. its just opening the same page in another tab with error "Object ref not set to instance of object" ---as its trying to reload the page but with no data available.

Comment: If you have the form like you have in your comment above, you will not get data. You have to use inputs which will be used in order to submit the values stored in these inputs to the server.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can find a working example to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @pitaridis for your valuable inputs.

i ended up doing like this:

```
`    <a asp-page="./Index" asp-page-handler="Export"
    asp-route-param1 = "@Model.data1"
    asp-route-param2 = "@Model.data2"
    asp-route-param3 = "@Model.data3"
    class="btn btn-info">
    Export
    </a>
`
```

Page handler is `OnGetExportAsync(...)`.On handler call **I am getting page refresh, Not sure Why** I have to again **repopulate** all the controls. Any idea on this ?

or other option could be to use the `OnGetAsync()` method & by passing a param that identify it as file download ?